# How to change legend from colorbar to "regular legend", still using color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Package `shinyscreenshot` is not able to print `plotly` colorbars ([shiny screenshot appears with colorless legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473002/shiny-screenshot-appears-with-colorless-legend#comment131515103_74473168)), so I'm looking for a way to still use color gradient but display the legend as if it were factorised.

---

## Example

**Origin plot with colorbar**

[image]

**Goal**

[image]

It doesn't mattert if there are 4, 5 or X datapoints in legend.

---

## MWE

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplotly(
  ggplot(data=mtcars,
         aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, color=qsec)) +
    geom_point()
)
```

Comment: `color=as.factor(qsec))`

Comment: That changes the whole column to factor, but I need the color gradient and only the legend look/behave like if it were factorised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly won't make a discrete legend for you, but you can still make it happen.

First, I assigned both the `ggplot` and `ggplotly` to objects.

```
plt <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(data=mtcars,
         aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, color=qsec)) +
    geom_point()
)

g <- ggplot(data=mtcars,
            aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, color=qsec)) +
  geom_point()
```

Next, use the data behind the `ggplot` object, combined with `mtcars`, to get a color by `qsec` data frame, so that you know what colors go with what values.

```
colByVal <- cbind(ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]], mtcars) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(colour, qsec) %>% arrange(qsec) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(qsec = median(qsec)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I figured that four or five values would be ideal. I just used `summary` to pick them. However, that's not necessary. Obviously, you can choose however many values you would like. These are the values I'll show in the legend.

```
parts <- summary(colByVal$qsec)
# drop the mean or median (the same color probably)
parts <- parts[-4]
```

Next, use `DescTools::Closest` to find the `qsec` values closest to the summary values.

```
vals <- lapply(parts, function(k) {
  DescTools::Closest(colByVal$qsec, k)[1]
}) %>% unlist(use.names = F)
```

Use these `qsec` values and the data frame with value by color to get the colors associated with these values.

```
cols <- colByVal %>% 
  filter(qsec %in% vals) %>% select(colour) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = F)
```

Using the colors and values (legend labels), use shapes and annotations (circles and text) to rebuild the legend. There is only one other element that needs to change between each legend item, the y position of the legend entry.

```
ys <- seq(from = .7, by = .07, length.out = length(cols))
```

There are two functions: shapes and annotations. Using `lapply`, walk through the values, colors, and y values through these functions to create the shapes and annotations.

```
# create shapes
shp <- function(y, cr) { # y0, and fillcolor
  list(type = "circle",
       xref = "paper", x0 = 1.1, x1 = 1.125,
       yref = "paper", y0 = y, y1 = y + .025,
       fillcolor = cr, yanchor = "center",
       line = list(color = cr))
}
# create labels
ano <- function(ya, lab) { # y and label
  list(x = 1.13, y = ya + .035, text = lab, 
       xref = "paper", yref = "paper", 
       xanchor = "left", yanchor = 'top', 
       showarrow = F)
}
# the shapes list
shps <- lapply(1:length(cols),
               function(j) {
                 shp(ys[j], cols[j])
               })
# the labels list
labs <- lapply(1:length(cols),
               function(i) {
                 ano(ys[i], as.character(vals[i]))
               })
```

When you use `ggplotly`, for some reason it ends an empty shape to the `ggplotly` object. This interferes with the ability to call for `shapes` in `layout` (which is the proper method). You have to force the issue with shapes. Additionally, the legend bar needs to go away. Once you drop the legend bar, Plotly will adjust the plot margins. The legend created with shapes and annotations will be hidden if you don't add the margins back.

```
# ggplot > ggplotly adds an empty shape; this conflicts with calling it in
#   layout(); we'll replace 'shapes' first
plt$x$layout$shapes <- shps
plt %>% hide_colorbar() %>% 
  layout(annotations = labs, showlegend = F, 
         margin = list(t = 30, r = 100, l = 50, b = 30, pad = 3))
```

[image]

All of that code in one chunk:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
# original plot
plt <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(data=mtcars,
         aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, color=qsec)) +
    geom_point()
)
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars,
            aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, color=qsec)) +
  geom_point()
# color by qsec values frame
colByVal <- cbind(ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]], mtcars) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(colour, qsec) %>% arrange(qsec) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(qsec = median(qsec)) %>% as.data.frame()

parts <- summary(colByVal$qsec)
# drop the mean or median (the same color probably)
parts <- parts[-4]

vals <- lapply(parts, function(k) {
  DescTools::Closest(colByVal$qsec, k)[1]
}) %>% unlist(use.names = F)

cols <- colByVal %>% 
  filter(qsec %in% vals) %>% select(colour) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = F)

ys <- seq(from = .7, by = .07, length.out = length(cols))

# create shapes
shp <- function(y, cr) { # y0, and fillcolor
  list(type = "circle",
       xref = "paper", x0 = 1.1, x1 = 1.125,
       yref = "paper", y0 = y, y1 = y + .025,
       fillcolor = cr, yanchor = "center",
       line = list(color = cr))
}
# create labels
ano <- function(ya, lab) { # y and label
  list(x = 1.13, y = ya + .035, text = lab, 
       xref = "paper", yref = "paper", 
       xanchor = "left", yanchor = 'top', 
       showarrow = F)
}
# the shapes list
shps <- lapply(1:length(cols),
               function(j) {
                 shp(ys[j], cols[j])
               })
# the labels list
labs <- lapply(1:length(cols),
               function(i) {
                 ano(ys[i], as.character(vals[i]))
               })
# ggplot > ggplotly adds an empty shape; this conflicts with calling it in
#   layout(); we'll replace 'shapes' first
plt$x$layout$shapes <- shps
plt %>% hide_colorbar() %>% 
  layout(annotations = labs, showlegend = F, 
         margin = list(t = 30, r = 100, l = 50, b = 30, pad = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer; you can change the shape and text of the legend while maintaining its gradient by using a combination of `scale_color_continuous` and `guides(color = guide_legend())`, but this will only show up as a `ggplot` object. For some reason, the legend disappears when you add the plot to `ggplotly()`, the legend disappears. I suspect that arguments specific to the legend [may need to be added to `ggplotly()`](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-showlegend) directly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, color = qsec)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_continuous(breaks = c(15, 17.5, 20, 22.5)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(
    reverse = T, 
    override.aes = list(shape = 19, size = 8))) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
p

p2 <- ggplotly(p) %>% layout(showlegend = T)
p2
```